# Analog to digital converter

Tags: analog, converter, digital-communications, signal-processing

I have very little electrical knowledge. So here is my question. I need to test some wiring harnesses if they grouped like it should be.

There is 70-80 points. differencing on the harness, these points are connecting together.

For example:

red cable left side point number 20, right side point number 32. So I will check if these two points connecting properly.

I want to use a Tablet PC for this purpose. So I need a converter that can send these 70 points' signals through USB to Tablet.

I do not ask for designing whole process. If you can point me to some direction, I will research it.

I forgot to mention. The converting have to be for both sides. I mean Tablet will tell which points it must check and then tablet will check the response signals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need anything as complicated as a A/D converter.  This can be done with digital logic signals easily enough.  On one side, tie each line to a digital output via a 1 kΩ resistor.  On the other side, tie each line high via separate 10 kΩ resistors, then each to its own digital input.  Then it becomes a matter of driving only one output at a time low with the others high and checking for that pattern at the other end.

This would be a lot easier to do in a microcontroller directly than to communicate all those digital inputs and outputs back to a tablet, which then runs thru this very simple algorithm. A micro can run thru the whole test nearly instantaneously in human time, so it can be doing it continually and setting a pass/fail indicator after every test.  The device would always be saying "fail" until a correct cable is plugged in, then it would pretty much instantly say "pass".

If you really needed information back to a tablet for logging or whatever, then you can use a micro with a serial port and external circuitry to provide a RS-232 connection via a DB-9 connector.  Then you can use a off the shelf USB to serial adapter to communicate between the tablet and the micro.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am currently searching for what you said and trying to see if I can do this :) I have very little electric knowledge.

Comment: Additionally, testing points can be change harness to harness so I want to keep the schemes on the tablet and I want to see which connection fails the test from tablet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger from your tablet you can use [IOIO board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/10748%E2%80%8E) by using this you can connect this board with the tablet through USB cable or through Bluetooth or you could interface [Arduino with Bluetooth](http://www.instructables.com/id/Cheap-2-Way-Bluetooth-Connection-Between-Arduino-a/?ALLSTEPS)  [2](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardBT?from=Main.ArduinoBoardBluetooth)